# Strong name, Manifest, and Code Signing

Tags: .net, manifest, code-signing, strongname

What order should these be done in?  I'm doing this from the command prompt for a .Net app.  I was able to do just strong name and code signing successfully, but when I tried all three, it doesn't look like it worked (==> Vista still trying to run the app with elevated privileges resulting in a prompt, though I set the requestedexecutionlevel at asInvoker)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Brian,

"Vista still trying to run the app with elevated privileges resulting in a prompt"

I think the prompt for running with higher privileges cannot be avoided by code signing, the only thing you avoid with code signing is the warning "application from unkown editor".

Comment: Yes, that is what the manifest is for, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the order should be the following:

1. Manifest
2. Codesign
3. SN Sign

This seems to be working now.  Not sure if I had 1 & 2 backwards before or if I did something wrong at the command prompt (I had a ;#2 tagged to the output resource--from a sample command--that I think is incorrect).  On that note, does anyone know a good reference for the command line tools?  I've been to the msdn pages, but they presume a lot of underlying knowledge.