# ClickOnce name, publisher and domain. What is it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, azure-devops, clickonce

I'm currently publishing 2 ClickOnce Application. One in VB and one in C#. I use Azure DevOps to do my builds and deployment. I have 2 * 2 = 4 builds:

1. VB staging
2. VB production
3. C# staging
4. C# production

I deploy on IIS where I have 4 web sites.

Here is the picture when I go on one of these website to install a version of one of my applications:

[image]

Help me identify where these value really come from before and after build or publication.

On the web page first: 4, 5 and 6. The name (4), the version (5) and the publisher (6) are hardcoded in html file deployed with click-once. Let'f forget about these one and focus on 1, 2, 3.

But, for me the most important is the values on the installer screen: 1, 2 and 3. The name (1), the domain (2) and the publisher (3) where are them coming from?

I ask this question because on my VB build everything seems correct but on my C# build I cannot get the correct value for my name, publisher and domain (1, 2, 3).

I use DevOps and Visual Studio Build task with MSBuild Arguments:

```
/target:publish 
/p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) 
/p:InstallURL=http://VBApp-staging.example.com/ 
/p:PublishURL=http://VBApp-staging.example.com/ 
/p:UpdateEnabled=true  
/p:UpdateMode=Foreground  
/p:ProductName="VB App Staging" 
/p:OutputPath="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Publish\\"
```

I also have my sln and proj file PropertyGroup setup for Staging and Release.

```
  </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Staging|AnyCPU' ">
    <PublishUrl>http://CSApp-staging.example.com/</PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl>http://CSApp-staging.example.com/</InstallUrl>
    <ProductName>CS Application Staging</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>Example Group</PublisherName>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Both VB and C# have defined similar PropertyGroup and similar Devops pipeline. Now when I run my pipeline for my VB software it seems that all values I can read on (1, 2, 3) are the one from MSBuild overridden arguments. But for my CS software I don't know. It seems the the arguments of MSbuild are doing nothing and all is comong from my project definition.

How is this possible? How can I make sure my MSbuild arguments works. Where these value from (1, 2, 3) come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this possible? How can I make sure my MSbuild arguments works.
>   Where these value from (1, 2, 3) come from?

`Value1` comes from msbuild property `ProductName` and `Value2` comes from msbuild property `PublishUrl`.

If these two properties only works for your VB project but not C# project, you should check the log of `C# project` to make sure you do choose the `Staging`+`AnyCPU` entry which passes corresponding definitions to publish process.

As for `Value3`,`PublisherName` property is not something used for this. There's no VS default option can control this, to get that work we need to add custom steps with [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-sign-setup-files-with-signtool-exe-clickonce?view=vs-2019). Here's one [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132305/net-clickonce-signing-results-in-unknown-publisher) and one [detailed document](https://github.com/erikest/SignClickOnce) you can follow with. Thanks to **Arin** and **erikest**!

Feel free to let me know if there's any update:)